# How to cache data for a session in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, caching, optimization

I'm using some REST Webservice calls in my iOS app, in response i'm getting pdf,ppt,.mp4 & etc documents list & on selection i'm fetching respective data from server & rendering it on screen.

1. Now When a user selects a particular file say, a .pdf doc then when he comes back and selects the same file then again i'm making a service call.(i want to avoid this).
2. Since it will take more time to load each time i thought to cache a file once clicked somewhere like in DocumentsDirectory or in Cache, then after if the file is there in my cache so don't invoke service call again just take it from cache & render.

So what is the best way of achieving this or how can i optimise my apps performance.
Any help is appreciated in advance.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Your thoughts along #2 -- saving content in a cache -- are a good strategy.
A very nice library that lets you store aribtrary data with simple expiration policy is [`EGOCache`](https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache), first announced on [Enormego's blog here](http://developers.enormego.com/view/egocache_objective_c_image_string_data_caching).

In your case, you'll simply use the RESTful URL as the key, and check the cache for its presence before fetching and saving if it's not there. Docs are a bit sparse, but [header file](https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache/blob/master/EGOCache.h) is very self-explanatory. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The first that comes to my mind is to look for existing categories / subclasses of the NSURL class. As an example, I use this category for locally decrypting content: http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/. The advantage is that the caching becomes transparent to the user this way, you would just load a resource using your extended version of the NSURL class.